# How to reset specific form element in a search form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search form that has different elements in it, checkboxes, selects, text fields etc. Each change is accompanied by an ajax call that gets the number of results as a sort of counter. I would like to reset only the previous element that caused the counter to return a value of 0.

I was thinking about keeping track of each change in a variable, and each time the counter evaluates to 0, I would then reset the element that caused the change. I however fear that this could force me to handle all the different elements differently with a lot of code and jumping around.

Is there a possible more elegant solution to the problem that anybody can think of? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of your form and js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by recording each change to the form with

```
$("#form_id").on("change", function(event) {
  //Event bubbling
  type = $(event.target).get(0).type;
  selector = $(event.target);
}
```

Then using the Strategy design pattern [(Javascript Strategy Design Pattern)](http://weblog.bocoup.com/the-strategy-pattern-in-javascript/), I reset each possible field type accordingly. Example for text field,

```
var Fields = {
  "text": {
    resetAction: function(fieldSelector) {
      fieldSelector.val('');
    }
  }
};

//To call the reset action for the type of field,
Fields[type].resetAction(selector);
```

I had to trigger a change event for hidden fields to have their changes also bubble.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment your question, but : if I understand correcty, there is a big form, and each change on *any* element, triggers an ajax call, that returns a resultset.

If this resultset size is zero, then, you want the form to reset to previous value.

That would mean, that only the last-changed value has to be tracked down, and reset ?

In this case, your `onchange` event callback should use `this` value to get current form element value, and ID. Then, as the resultset comes back, set back the stored value to that element if there are no rows.

Otherwise, if the form is managed globally, you could always store it with a `.clone()` call, then `.remove()` it and `.insert()` the clone back if the resultset is empty.

PS : i know this solution not really *elegant* :)

Comment: This actually pointed me in the right direction. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX module could return a JSON-Encoded string with the data causing this event to occur (PHP-Function: JSON_encode) and from there on, you can cycle through the erroneous values resetting them and displaying further informations. i.e. "Your E-Mail seems to be invalid".

PHP: See JSON_encode
JavaScript: See getElementsByTagName('input') (or textarea or select)
Note: In case of a select item, you may rather want to change the Attribute "selectedIndex" than "value".